# Android Studio - Activity with image crashes emulator but works in phone

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-logcat

I added a new `Activity` to my Android Studio. This Activity has a picture. Here is the code of my xml.file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:showIn="@layout/auxguide1"
tools:context=".AuxGuide1">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:src="@drawable/logoauxguide"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

and here is my code of the java class
package com.example.gonalo.meu;

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class AuxGuide1 extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.auxguide1);
        int secondsDelayed = 1;
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                startActivity(new Intent(AuxGuide1.this, MainActivity.class));

                finish();
            }
        }, secondsDelayed * 4000);
    }

}
```

It works perfectly in my phone, but when I run it on the emulator it says "sorry the application has stopped"

This is my logcat

```
03-28 08:01:20.513 29031-29031/com.example.gonalo.meu W/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 79051908 byte allocation with 1048576 free bytes and 63MB until OOM"
03-28 08:01:20.514 29031-29031/com.example.gonalo.meu D/skia: --- allocation failed for scaled bitmap
03-28 08:01:20.514 29031-29031/com.example.gonalo.meu D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
03-28 08:01:20.515 29031-29031/com.example.gonalo.meu E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                 Process:   com.example.gonalo.meu, PID: 29031
                                                                     java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 79051908 byte allocation with 1048576 free bytes and 63MB until OOM
                                                                        at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
                                                                        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
                                                                        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
                                                                        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
                                                                        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1080)
                                                                        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2635)
                                                                        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2540)
                                                                        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:870)
                                                                        at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:152)
                                                                        at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:140)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:57)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:53)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:106)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:972)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1031)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:746)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:971)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:831)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:276)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
                                                                        at com.example.gonalo.meu.AuxGuide1.onCreate(AuxGuide1.java:13)
                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
03-28 08:01:25.402 29031-29031/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 29031 SIG: 9
```

It won't stop my work on the project, but it is usefull for me to know why this happens. Would appreciate help.
[image: My application has stopped (emulator only)]

Comment: what is the dimension of the image `logoauxguide` in `AuxGuide1` xml?

Comment: @FabinPaul how do i search for the dimension of the image? i knew where it was but cant remember where is it.

Comment: Try remove the line `android:src="@drawable/logoauxguide"` from your xml

Comment: If the application works without the same exception, then the image `logoauxguide` has high resolution and hence android device cannot load the entire image into memory (`OutOfMemoryError`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an android device must display an image, it must load the entire image into memory. In your case `logoauxguide` is high resolution image, thus the entire image will not fit into the device memory. Hence `OutOfMemoryError` will occur.

But a device with larger memory, in this case your phone will be able to load the image into memory.

If you want to display the image, you must reduce its resolution in any image editing tool (640x480 will be just fine). Beside you don't want a higher memory image increasing your apk size :)

Comment: is there any option to make the memory larger?

Comment: Memory is hardware constraint and cannot be changed.(depends on the device old nexus one had only 512mb of ram while latest nexus 6p have 3gb of ram)